# Why I cannot load property POJO using YAML in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have read numerous posts, questions, examples and all that it should work but for whatever reasons it does not....

Can anyone tell me why this does not work??

```
@Configuration()
@PropertySource("users.yml")
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class UserConfig {


    public String test;
    public List<String> states;
    public List<User> users;

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String pw;
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

**And the output is** `UserConfig(test='yeah im tested', states=[], users=[])`

for given YAML

```
test: 'yeah im tested'
states:
  - 'Up'
  - 'Down'
users:
  -
    username: 'Gienek'
    pw: 'niegienek'
    roles:
      - 'rola1'
      - 'rola2'
```

**Note:**
using `states: 'Up','Down'` fills states list.

Please note also that it works partially.

Comment: Shouldn't it be @Value("${test}") private String test;

Comment: As i already pointed out - this particular `test` field - works. `UserConfig(test='yeah im tested', states=[], users=[])`

Comment: keep your values as comma separated in yaml like states: up, down....... ***@Value("${states}")    
String[] states***

Comment: as stated in notes - yes, states written as `states : val val` works - without `@Value`

Comment: @SwaritAgarwal how about whole `User` objects?

Comment: Would you have a try with  **@Value("states[0]" String state** seems @value is not made for complex type

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/501 good read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207415/discussion-between-swarit-agarwal-and-antoniossss).

Comment: tried this? https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/

Comment: So it seams yamls are ummm partially supported??

Comment: OK it seams that this is hidden limitation of yaml processing by spring impl.Will leave that be.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more precise, it is a "known" fact that Spring Boot does not want to support `@PropertySource` to support yml files properly, as this not a "standard" to use `@Propertysource` in a Spring boot project... Here is the link of the discussion:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486.

You can also try using, like recommended, a `EnvironmentPostProcessor` : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context

I'd recommend any to give a try to application.yml, unless you have an exploitation constraint.

One solution is to copy the content of your `users.yml` into `application.yml` which will definitly fits your needs.

> src/main/resources/application.yml

```
test: 'yeah im tested'
states:
  - 'Up'
  - 'Down'
users:
  -
    username: 'Gienek'
    pw: 'niegienek'
    roles:
      - 'rola1'
      - 'rola2'
```

> UserConfig.java

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class UserConfig {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes we have just discovered that yaml parsing of application.yml (application* named files) works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that this is simply limitation of how Spring hadles yaml files and I am out of luck without custom implementation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16381